# Google script keep uploading files in Same folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have two files: code.gs and form.html. I changes folder name in code.gs but still It uploads in same folder i.e. Student Files.

form.html

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name..">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
           onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }
</script>

<style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {   

    var folderName = "Test";
    var exist = true;
    try {
      var folderName = DocsList.getFolder(folderName)
      }

    catch(err) {
      exist=false
    }

    if (exist) {
      folder = folderName;
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);=
    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();
  } catch (error) {
    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

The code.gs file consists of a variable folderName.

This name is checked and if folder of this name doen't exists A new folder is created. but here New folder is not getting created. Instead the file is getting uploaded in same folder i.e. Student Files.

Comment: your gs code is using DocsList which is deprecated and does NOT work anymore. Replace it with DriveApp after reading the documentation  : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app

Comment: Thanks. DriveApp works lika a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous Answer was just the copy of the code asked in question.

The DocsList.getFolder(folderName) function may not be getting any folder, thats why the file gets uploaded in the pervious folder.

Comment: Thank you. I got the problem.

Comment: I used DriveApp instead of DockList coz DockList is depricated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `code.gs`:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {   

    var folderName = "Test";
    var exist = true;
    try {
      var folderName = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName)
      }

    catch(err) {
      exist=false
    }

    if (exist) {
      folder = folderName;
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);=
    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();
  } catch (error) {
    return error.toString();
  }

}
```